# Javascript Function If True

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

I am calling sub functions that are connected to if statements in my function. Though the sub functions return true or false, it doesn't work

> ```
>    if (functionAAA()){
>        alert("111111111");
>
>        if (functionBBB()){
>                       alert("2222222");
>
>            if (functionCCC()){
>                           alert("333333333333");
>
>
>
>            }            
>        }
>    }
> ```

functionAAA, functionBBB, functionCCC return true. I was expecting to get these alerts but they don't work. what am I doing wrong?

I think the problem is the function side.. functionAAA definition is

```
function functionAAA(){
    var indexId = 1;

    var dataItem = datasourceAppList.at(indexId);
    var deviceKey = localStorage.getItem('LsDeviceKey');
    var baseUrl = localStorage.getItem('LsBaseUrl');    
    var errorMessageInfoText;
    var status

    $.ajax({

        url: baseUrl + '/test/cloud/FE/1.0/test.php',
        data: {
            PAR1: dataItem.par1,
            PAR2: dataItem.par2,
            PAR3: deviceKey,
            PAR4: dataItem.par3,
            PAR5: "5664456"
        },
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: function () {
            showErrorDialog("Key Validation Failure");;
        }

    }).done(function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (k, v) {

           // alert("k  " + k + "  v  " + v);
            if (k == 'STATUS') {
                status = v;
            } else if (k == 'ERROR_MESSAGE') {

                errorMessageInfoText = v;
            }
        })


        if (status == 'TRUE') {
            alert("ok");
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        };

    });    

}
```

the other functions directly return true;

by the way, I receive the "ok" alert in the function

Comment: Let's have a look at these functions then. Can you post them here?

Comment: [The problem is not in this code](http://jsfiddle.net/A9aTU/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure your code. The anonymous function inside `.done()` is executed after `functionAAA` has already completed and returned `undefined`. AJAX calls are Asynchronous, after all.

`$.ajax` returns a `promise`, so one option is to use [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
function functionAAA(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
    });
}

functionAAA().then(function() {
    alert("111111111");
    if (functionBBB()){
        alert("2222222");
        if (functionCCC()){
            alert("333333333333");
        }            
    }
});
```

see it in action [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2D5P/).

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't return anything. You can't do an asynchronous call and return the result — that's what it means to be asynchronous. If you want to do something after the ajax call completes, you'll need to give the function a callback and call it instead of attempting to return from the ajax handler.

Answer (score 0):

The script below works for me.  Can you please post your functionAAA, BBB, etc?

```
    <script>
    function functionAAA() {
        return true;
    }
    if(functionAAA()){
       alert("hi");
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this and make your ajax call synchronous so it waits for the response, checks it and returns true/false accordingly. Right now it shouldn't return anything.

```
async: false
```

Answer (score -3):

try...

```
 if (functionAAA()){
           alert("111111111");

           if (functionBBB()){
                          alert("2222222");

              else if (functionCCC()){
                              alert("333333333333");



               }            
           }
       }
```